# Delete all URLs that are not of the same domain

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm new to bash, so please do give me an explanation to your answer. I've looked in to other similar questions but I'm still stuck. I have a text file that contains about 4k URLs. I would like to delete all URL's that are not a part of a domain.

For example, I only want URLs from the domain `http://www.example.com`. The text file also has URLs like `mail.example.com` which I'm not interested in. If i were asked to write a regex of interested URLs it would be `^http://www.example.com/*`.

I tried `grep -no '^http:\/\/www.example.com\*' listofURLs.txt`, but this gave back all lines along with line number that contain `http://www.example.com`.

Now i could use `sed` and delete all other lines, but that's not a neat solution. I was wondering if there was a easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show an excerpt of `listofURLs.txt`

Comment: Why are you using the `-n` option? Do you need the line numbers?

Comment: Well I can't give you the exact contents of the file. The file consits of URLs like `http://mail.example.com, https://www.facebook.com/exapmle, https://www.youtube.com/exaple, http://www.example.com/foo-bar/` etc.

Comment: @Barmar, well like I told, I thought I'll use `sed` and delete all other line numbers. That's why I used the `-n ` option.

Comment: Are they one URL per line, or multiple on the same line?

Comment: @Barmar, One URL per line.

Comment: Then `grep regexp filename` should return only the matching URLs. Why isn't that working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
grep '^http://www\.example\.com' listofURLs.txt > listofExampleURLs.txt
```

There's no need to use `-o`, that's only needed when you need to get just the part of the line that matches the regexp.